# TeXLive 2020-2021-2022 performance

Tags: pdftex, texlive, latexmk, performance

**Disclaimer:** This post is a bit long… if you have no concerns with the TeX Live ecosystem behavior and LaTeX compile time, just ignore it! :)

I have a “complex” project ([thesis template](https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis)) that uses BibLaTeX for bibliography.  I tried to compile the [branch 7.0.0](https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis/tree/7.0.0) ([ZIP here](https://github.com/joaomlourenco/novathesis/archive/refs/heads/7.0.0.zip)) of the project with the following command line
`latexmk -time -shell-escape -synctex=1 -output-format=pdf -file-line-error -silent -pdf template`
and four different versions of TeX Live (2020 to 2022).

The timings are all in seconds and were obtained using macOS Ventura in a MacBook Pro early 2018. All the times are an average of 3 out of 4 executions (always ignored the first execution for each version to benefit from disk caching). The standard deviations are low.

My observations are:

- The compilation times for `biber` have been increasing (32% since TL 2020). See line (2).
- The compilation times for `pdflatex` increased >25% from TL 2020 to TL 2021/2. See line (1).
- In TL2022 the compilation times for `pdflatex` increase considerably (>40%) for the 2nd and subsequent executions. See column TL 2020, lines (1) vs. (3), (5), and (6).
- `latexmk` behaves differently in different versions.

  - Without a `latexmkrc`file, it skips one execution of `pdflatex`in TL 2021-dev and runs `biber`twice in TL 2022.
  - With a `latexmkrc`file (see copy of the file below), which addresses the dependencies in glossaries, it skips one execution of `pdflatex`in TL 2021-dev and TL 2022.

Any hints on the following:

- Why does `latexmk` behave so differently with the different versions of TL? That last execution of `pdflatex` is necessary?
- Why is `biber` getting slower?
- Why is `pdflatex` slower for the 2nd and subsequent runs in TL 2020?

#### Run time(s) *without* `latexmkrc`

|  | 2020 | 2021 | 2021-dev | 2022 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **pdflatex** | 4.11 | 5.89 | 5.19 | 5.10 | (1) |
| **biber** | 1.59 | 1.84 | 1.72 | 2.10 | (2) |
| **pdflatex** | 4.29 | 6.38 | 5.62 | 7.21 | (3) |
| **biber** | ---- | ---- | ---- | 2.09 | (4) |
| **pdflatex** | 4.30 | 6.47 | 5.80 | 7.23 | (5) |
| **pdflatex** | 4.37 | 6.37 | ---- | 7.25 | (6) |
| **ACC TIME** | **(*)19.80** | **(*)28.39** | **(*)19.43** | **33.78** |  |

(*) Glossaries are not properly generated without a `latexmkrc`

(----) `latexmk` did not run this command (or did not report its timing)

#### Run time(s) *with* `latexmkrc`

|  | 2020 | 2021 | 2021-dev | 2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **pdflatex** | 4.03 | 5.72 | 5.02 | 5.39 |
| **makeglossaries** | ---- | ---- | 1.59 | 1.69 |
| **biber** | 1.53 | 1.68 | 1.66 | 2.08 |
| **pdflatex** | 4.35 | 6.24 | 5.62 | 7.22 |
| **biber** | 1.61 | 1.69 | 1.72 | 2.07 |
| **makeglossaries** | ---- | ---- | 1.52 | 1.56 |
| **pdflatex** | 4.34 | 6.32 | 5.63 | 7.25 |
| **pdflatex** | 4.35 | 6.29 | ---- | ---- |
| —————— | —————— | —————— | —————— | ————————— |
| **Acc time** | 24.53 | 32.90 | 23.86 | 29.46 |

#### Software versions

| TeXLive | versions. |
| --- | --- |
| **2020** | Latexmk, John Collins, 26 Dec. 2019. Version 4.67 |
|  | This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex) |
|  | biber version: 2.14 |
|  | Makeglossaries Version 4.45 (2020-01-18) |
| ————— | ———————————————————————————————————————————————————— |
| **2021** | Latexmk, John Collins, 29 September 2020. Version 4.70b |
|  | This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex) |
|  | biber version: 2.16 |
|  | Makeglossaries Version 4.45 (2020-01-18) |
| ————— | ———————————————————————————————————————————————————— |
| **2021-dev** | Latexmk, John Collins, 17 Mar. 2022. Version 4.77 |
|  | This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2022/dev) (preloaded format=pdflatex) |
|  | biber version: 2.17 |
|  | Makeglossaries Version 4.49 (2021-11-01) |
| ————— | ———————————————————————————————————————————————————— |
| **2022** | Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79 |
|  | This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex) |
|  | biber version: 2.18 |
|  | Makeglossaries Version 4.51 (2022-11-02) |

#### The `latexmkrc` file

```
if ( ! $silent ) {
    if ($^O =~ /darwin/) {
       print "DIAGNOSTICS = Operating System Detected: Mac OSX\n";
       $filesep = '/'
    } elsif ($^O =~ /linux/) {
       print "DIAGNOSTICS = Operating System: Linux\n";
       $filesep = '/'
    } else {
       print "DIAGNOSTICS = Operating System: Windows\n";
       $filesep = '\\'
    }
}

add_cus_dep('glo', 'gls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
add_cus_dep('acn', 'acr', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
add_cus_dep('slo', 'sls', 0, 'makeglo2gls');
add_cus_dep('cho', 'chs', 0, 'makeglo2gls');

sub makeglo2gls {
    my ($base_name, $dir) = fileparse( $_[0] ); #handle -outdir param by splitting path and file, ...
    if ($^O =~ /darwin/) {
        system "makeglossaries -q -d '$dir' '$base_name'"; #macos
    } elsif ($^O =~ /linux/) {
        system "makeglossaries -q -d '$dir' '$base_name'"; #unix
    } else {
        system "makeglossaries", "-q", "-d", "$dir", "$base_name"; #windows
    };
}

push @generated_exts, 'glo', 'gls', 'glg';
push @generated_exts, 'acn', 'acr', 'alg';
push @generated_exts, 'slo', 'sls', 'slg';
push @generated_exts, 'cho', 'chs', 'chg';
$clean_ext .= ' %R.ist %R.xdy';
```

Comment: On which OS did you check this? Did you run every command several times and calculate the means? Especially the OS is critical, "benchmarks are like air conditioners, they don't work if you open Windows".

Comment: it is not really suprising that the second compilations are slower (after you run biber + makeindex and similar)  as then the code has more to do to resolve references. Apart from this: check your log for warnings, and don't use the catoptions package.

Comment: @skillmon I’m using macOS Ventura in a MacBook Pro early 2018. And yes, all the times above are average of 3 out of 4 executions (always ignored the first execution for each version). The standard deviations are low.

Comment: @Ulrike I guess there must be something more there, as there was no significant time increase  TL 2020 and TL 2021.  Not even in TL 2021-dev (which was almost TL2022).

Comment: Question for the OP: Are you able to determine how much of the time is spent loading the TeX files (prior to the first line of body text), and how much time is spent in the document body? If most of the time is spent loading, or not, then that will make a more noticeable difference with very long documents. If you keep your eye on the screen during load time, is there any particular package or executable that cuases noticeable hesitation while it loads?

Comment: Are your times in seconds or minutes or ...?

Comment: Versions of latexmk before 4.75 failed to report timings of some processing steps (e.g., the one that calls makeglossaries).  You have to look earlier in the output to see whether makeglossaries was run.

Comment: You may get insight on why latexmk does the extra run of pdflatex by removing the -silent option to latexmk.  Then latexmk will indicate what file(s) changed to provoke it to do each run, just before the run.  To reduce the volume of output from pdflatex, use the option -interaction=batchmode.